# AngularJS: Factory and filters - factory is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, factory

I have this code, and it works:

```js
var app = angular.module('twitterApp', ['twitterApp.services', 'ngSanitize']);
app.filter('clearImage', function () {
    return function (text) {
        var str = text.replace(/_normal./g, '.');
        return str;
    };
});
app.filter('links', function () {
    return function (text) {
        var str = text.replace(/@([^ ']+)/g, function(u, screen_name) {
            var link = '<a target=blank href="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=' + screen_name + '">' + u + '</a>';
            return link;            
        });
        str = str.replace(/#([^ ']+)/g, function (t, hash) {
            var link = '<a target=blank href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/' + hash + '?src=hash">' + t + '</a> ';
            return link;
                    
        });
        return str;
    };
});
```

I am trying to be more object oriented and modular, so I have made the following code, but it is not working:

```js
var app = angular.module('twitterApp', ['twitterApp.services', 'ngSanitize']);

app.factory('StratoFactory', function() {
    var factory = {};
    return {
    removeNormalStringFromImage : function(text) {       
            var str = text.replace(/_normal./g, '.');
            return str;       
    },
    userName2Link : function(text) { 
        
        var str = text.replace(/@([^ ']+)/g, function(u, screen_name) {
            var link = '<a target=blank href="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=' + screen_name + '">' + u + '</a>';
            return link;    
        });
        str = str.replace(/#([^ ']+)/g, function (t, hash) {
            var link = '<a target=blank href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/' + hash + '?src=hash">' + t + '</a> ';
            return link;                    
        });
        return str;
    }
    };
    return factory;
    
});


app.filter('clearImage', function(StratoFactory) { 
    return function(text) {
    StratoFactory.removeNormalStringFromImage(text);
    };
});
app.filter('links', function(StratoFactory) { 
    return function(text) {
    StratoFactory.userName2Link(text);
    };
});
```

Can someone explain me the reason what is wrong with the second version of the code? Thanks!

Comment: javascript sandbox would be very helpful

Comment: Hi @STEVER , I have been using the code from this page [link](http://www.chaosm.net/blog/2014/05/24/angularjs-twitter-authentication-with-oauth-io/). Only, I have added those filters and applied them to the JSON response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the solution! There wasn't any error in the console, because everything was structured ok. But the problem was that my filters weren't returning anything. So I have simply added a return, and now everything is ok. Really a banal mistake. Here is the code:

```
var app = angular.module('twitterApp', ['twitterApp.services', 'ngSanitize']);

app.factory('StratoFactory', function() {
var factory = {};
factory.removeNormalStringFromImage = function(text) {       
        var str = text.replace(/_normal./g, '.');
        return str;       
},
factory.userName2Link = function(text) { 

    var str = text.replace(/@([^ ']+)/g, function(u, screen_name) {
        var link = '<a target=blank href="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=' +        screen_name + '">' + u + '</a>';
        return link;    
    });
    str = str.replace(/#([^ ']+)/g, function (t, hash) {
        var link = '<a target=blank href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/' + hash + '?src=hash">' +     t + '</a> ';
        return link;                    
    });
    return str;
};
return factory;
});

app.filter('clearImage', function(StratoFactory) { 
return function(text) {
**return** StratoFactory.removeNormalStringFromImage(text);
};
});
app.filter('links', function(StratoFactory) { 
return function(text) {
**return**  StratoFactory.userName2Link(text);
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two return statements in your factory.
you need to create an object, assign method to it, then return it.

try this:

```
app.factory('StratoFactory', function() {
    var factory = {};
    factory.removeNormalStringFromImage = function(text) {
            var str = text.replace(/_normal./g, '.');
            return str;
    }
    factory.userName2Link = function(text) {

        var str = text.replace(/@([^ ']+)/g, function(u, screen_name) {
            var link = '<a target=blank href="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=' + screen_name + '">' + u + '</a>';
            return link;
        });
        str = str.replace(/#([^ ']+)/g, function (t, hash) {
            var link = '<a target=blank href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/' + hash + '?src=hash">' + t + '</a> ';
            return link;
        });
        return str;
    }

    return factory;
});
```

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake, but it still is not working. I don't have any errors on the page, but when I apply the filter on the JSON, the page is not showing anything.